# Thousands of E0434352.CLR exceptions during test run in Azure Pipelines using LOCAL agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline which runs unit tests (nunit) using a **local** agent.

Everything worked OK until I moved to a new laptop. Without any changes to my repository or build settings, the logs of builds generated now are now full of these messages:

> 2019-02-06T10:21:22.7514187Z [11:21:22] Exception: E0434352.CLR

There are over 7000 messages for less than 100 unit tests. Some of the tests are UI tests (with TestStack.White) and some are web tests (with Selenium).
The errors don't seem to affect the test execution, because tests are passing OK (or failing appropriately if there are issues).

The only thing that has changed is a newer version of Windows 10 build and potentially a newer version of the build agent which I had to re-download.

**How can I debug that, because the error does not say anything?**

<s>Can it be related to the version of the build agent?

Does the build agent executable updates itself?</s>

In attempt to get rid of the error I have updated the agent from v144 to v146, but no change (64bit, as my Windows)

Comment: Whats the value of the system.debug variable? @ Build -> Edit -> Variables. Might it be true?

Comment: @KristófTóth - thanks for your input - it is false though. (I will turn it on an see if that helps in debugging)

Comment: The hosted agent is Microsoft's. Unless the build agent is installed on your laptop, this has nothing to do with your new laptop.

Comment: @DanielMann oh my, I must have had a brain damage. Of course I mean a **local** agent. I am **not** using the cloud hosted agent. Edited the question. Damn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uncheck the "Collect advanced diagnostics in case of catastrophic failures" under the test task.

**There's no need to disable the test rerun!**

[image]

(This is as per @GregM's answer, however I couldn't edit his post to make this stand out a bit more in his text)

Answer (score 10):

its a bug in AzureDevOps.
You can read about it here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/446334/hundreds-of-e0434352clr-exceptions-during-test-run.html

You can do a workaround by disabling test rerun.
If you don't want to do that, I've managed to disable them by turning off:
"Collect advanced diagnostics in case of catastrophic failures" in the visual studio test task.

Comment: Thanks for posting this here. This is actually my post on dev community, but indeed it makes sense to link it here:)

Comment: I had to look it up, the Collect advanced diagnostics checkbox is near the rerun tests checkbox in the details of the run tests task in azure.